# $f(x)=ax^2+b$, if $f(x) $has a tangent line of $y=12x-13$ at $x=2$, find $a$ and $b$.

Tags: derivatives

So I know I can say that $4a+b=11$ (by plugging in $2$), but I'm not sure where I can go from there. I've been looking for a second equation so I can do systems of equations, but I can't seem to find one. My thought was to isolate a, and say $a=\frac{11-b}{4}$ then say $\frac{11-b}{4}+b=11$, but that results in $b = 11$ and $a = 0$.  I don't think that is correct. Please help.

Comment: $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x,f(x))$. So $f'(2)=4a=12$, you get $a=3$.

Comment: sorry, can you explain in more detail? I'm confused.

Comment: Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: You're right that you need two equations; you found one just fine.

You tagged the question with "derivatives", so presumably you know they should be involved somewhere. But you haven't *used* any derivatives yet, so that should suggest how you might find a second equation.

Comment: Thank you, I got it

Answer (score 1):

First, what you have done is flawed. When you plug in the value of a in terms of b into the same equation, you have forgotten that the equation is actually $4a+b=11$ and not $a+b=11$. That's the reason you have got values for a and b when you actually shouldn't get any.

Now coming to the solution, $f'(x)$ gives you the slope of the curve at a certain point. So at the point x=2 the slope of the line is 4a(obtained through f'(x)). Now, from the equation of the tangent we get 4a=12. Therefore, a=3. b is suppose isn't a problem.